# Jenkins Theme Manager plugin not applying themes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've recently set up an instance of Jenkins running on Kubernetes, and I've installed the Theme Manager as well as the Material, Solar, and Dark themes. However, when I go to change the theme in `Configure System -> Built-In Themes`, all the themes are there, however they all look exactly the same as the default, and selecting them changes nothing? Is there something that I'm missing here?

[image: What I see in my settings]

Comment: same problem here. currently running Jenkins 2.346.3 inside a docker container behind a reverse-proxy

Answer (score 1):

It's because your browser is blocking the loading of the CSS assets (The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy).

I run it into a container as well and when I change the Jenkins URL in the admin config to "localhost" it fix the problem.

Comment: In my case, I run Jenkins for Windows Desktop, and also suffered from this issue. I headed to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" and edited the "Jenkins Location" -> "Jenkins URL", and changed `http://localhost:<port>/` to `http://<hostName>:<port>/`